# What is the difference between "organize one's time" and "manage one's time"?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me what the difference is between *organize one's time* and *manage one's time*? For example:

> Kate meets her deadlines because she's good at **organizing her time**
>
> Kate meets her deadlines because she's good at **managing her time**

Comment: Only one is correct: one manages their time, one does not organize it.

Comment: You can find plenty of instances of "organize your time" on the web, which is why I asked the question.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=organize+your+time%2C+manage+your+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Corganize your time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanage your time%3B%2Cc0